Applying for DS-160 form for both husband and wife
My brother and his wife want to visit the US. If he fills a DS-160 form for himself and his wife, when he schedules the interview, will it be possible to schedule the interview together for both? If so, what is the process?

Where are they applying from ? Which country ?

They are applying from Pakistan
